# How to describe the location (North, South, East and West) of a country/city with respect to another country/city

Tags: meaning, standard-german, position

I have read the following ways of telling the location of a city within a country. So, which one of these is common and correct?

1. Die Stadt liegt im Süden von Deutschland.
2. Die Stadt ist im Süden von Deutschland.
3. Die Stadt ist südlich von Deutschland.

Comment: How sure are you that the combination of Question and Exposition is not equating, for instance South London with South of London?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### liegt – ist

German has a couple of verbs that do not describe an action, but the kind of being located somewhere. English has such verbs too, but in English they are mainly used to describe positions of people, not of things:

> to sit = sitzen
> to lie =  liegen
> to stand = stehen

Sometimes some of these verbs can also be used to describe positions of things (*"The picture **hangs** on the wall"* = *»Das Bild **hängt** an der Wand.«*) but the main usage of most of these verbs is still for people in English.

In German we use these verbs much more, and we use them also for unanimated things:

> The book **is** on the shelf. = Das Buch **steht** im Regal. (because it's in an upright position)
> The book **is** on the table. = Das Buch **liegt** auf dem Tisch. (because it's lying flat there)
> The broom **is** in the closet. = Der Besen **steht** im Schrank.
> The carpet **is** on the floor. = Der Teppich **liegt** auf dem Boden.

So, when something is in a horizontal position (i.e. not upright) you usually use the verb *liegen = to lie* to describe the position. And because cities, states, countries, continents and all other geographic entities nestle against the surface of the planet earth, you use the verb *liegen* to describe their kind of being positioned in German.

Grammatically it's correct to use the verb *»ist«* (or another form of the verb *»sein«*), but it's unidiomatic. No native German speaker would use *»ist«.* But when learners of German use this verb, we know what they mean, but we also know at the same moment that German is a foreign language to them.

So:

- absolutely correct, good style and idiomatic:

  > Die Stadt **liegt** im Süden von Deutschland.
- grammatically correct, but bad style and unidiomatic:

  > Die Stadt *ist* im Süden von Deutschland.

---

#### im Süden – südlich

These are true statements (München = Munich is in Germany, Innsbruck is in Austria, i.e. not in Germany):

> true: München liegt im Süden von Deutschland.
> true: Innsbruck liegt südlich von Deutschland.

These are false statements:

> false: München liegt südlich von Deutschland.
> false: Innsbruck liegt im Süden von Deutschland.

- **im Süden**
  This means: inside the region, but close to the southern border. You usually use *»im Süden«* to decribe the location of sub-regions within a region that contains this sub-region.

  > Florida **liegt im Süden** der USA. = Florida **is in the south of** the USA.
  > Miami **liegt im Süden** der USA. = Miami **is in the south of** the USA.
  >
  > Sussex **liegt im Süden** Englands. = Sussex **is in the south of** England.
  > Brighton **liegt im Süden** Englands. = Brighton **is in the south of** England.
  >
  > Bayern **liegt im Süden** Deutschlands. = Bavaria **is in the south of** Germany.
  > München **liegt im Süden** Deutschlands. = Munich **is in the south of** Germany.

  As you can read from the examples, the containing geographic region is usually given in the genitive case. But it is also possible to use the preposition *»von«* and then the dative form. But this possibility comes with restrictions:

  - genitive is always correct and it's preferred:

    - no article
      *im Süden Englands, im Süden Deutschlands*
    - with article

      - masculine or neuter
        *im Süden des Senegals, im Süden des Kosovo*
      - feminine or plural
        *im Süden der Schweiz, im Süden der Vereinigten Arabischen Emirate*
  - correct: *»von« + dative* if the name has no article
    *im Süden von England, im Süden von Deutschland*
  - correct: *»vom« + dative* if the name has an article and is masculine or neuter
    *im Süden vom Senegal, im Süden vom Kosovo*
  - **bad style:** *»von« + dative* if the name has an article and is feminine or plural
    <del>*im Süden von der Schweiz, im Süden von den Vereinigten Arabischen Emiraten*</del>
- **südlich**

  This means: outside the region, south of it. In theory it should be correct to use the region in the genitive case too, but that's unidiomatic. German native speakers always use it with *»von« + dative.*

  > Österreich **liegt südlich** von Deutschland. = Austria **is south** of Germany.
  > Italien **liegt südlich** von Österreich. = Italy **is south** of Austria.

Comment: I don't think it's the plural as such that makes the "von" + dative bad style, ot's the article. At least, "im Süden von der Schweiz" sounds just as clumsy to me as your plural examples.

Comment: While this is changing, there is still a large number of English speakers for whom "lay" is only transitive (German _legen_).  The intransitive verb is "lie" (German _liegen_).  "Munich lies in the southern part of Germany."  When people say "I am laying on the bed" my initial reaction is still to wonder "_what_ are you laying on the bed?"  The book is lying flat on the table.  The student is laying a book on the table.

Comment: This is of course complicated by two facts, namely that the past tense of "lie" is "lay" (German _lag_) and that "lie" is also the base form of an entirely other verb (German _lügen_).  I believe this confusing situation accounts for the increasing intransitive use of _lay_ without a corresponding increase in the intransitive use of _set_ (which seems to remain confined to dialects that have also been using _lay_ intransitively for much longer).  One still tends not to find intransitive "lay" in modern formal use (for example in news articles other than when quoting colloquial speech).

Comment: "No native German speaker would use »ist«." Now you make me cry as a native (Swiss) German speaker. I much prefer "ist" over "liegt" and I never hear anyone around me say "liegt".

Comment: Interesting that German is so averse to using _sein_ with toponyms. The Scandinavian languages all use ‘stand/sit/lie’ the same way – in fact more so than German, also to express progressive aspect (“I am reading” = ‘I stand/sit/lie and read’) – but are all quite happy to use _be_ with toponyms when the focus is on _identifying_ rather than _describing_ its location. For example, the equivalent of “Berlin ist in Deutschland” is a plain statement of geographical fact, whereas the equivalent of “Berlin liegt in Deutschland” is descriptive, focusing on the physicality of the location.

Comment: To add to what @YanickSalzmann said - as a native speaker from the south of Germany, "ist" does not feel unidiomatic to me at all. I think I use both "liegt" and "ist" interchangeably.

Comment: @Noiralef: same here in Hesse

Comment: @Noiralef Same here in Hannover. And we of all Germans should know. (Written language may prefer "liegen" but "Flensburg ist doch ganz im Norden" sounds perfectly fine.) Edit: Although we should really know, we ain't always right: "Flensburg ist im Norden" yields exactly 0 hits; with "liegt" 1900. My last defense would be "all of the internet is written language".

Answer (score 5):

In German, things are generally not described as just "being" at a location, but instead are described as "doing" something there. This is often "lying" - "liegen" when the thing is wide and flat like a city, but other verbs are possible, so "sitting" - "sitzen" or "standing" - "stehen", depending on what is appropriate in the situation. I don't think "sein" is actually wrong, but it's not the custom to use it for location when a more descriptive verb is available. Separate from that issue is whether to use "im Süden" or "südlich von". That depends on the intended meaning and I think more context would be needed to answer, but with respect to Germany "südlich von" would be used when what you're talking about is past the actual border and is actually in Austria or Switzerland. For two cities you'd probably use "südlich von": "München liegt südlich von Berlin."

Comment: südlich von = south of. Im Süden von = in the south of. I'd s say that 'sein' is ok, but lower register than 'liegen' or whatever other verb used

Answer (score 3):

I would like to see the genitive here: *‹Die Stadt› liegt im Süden Deutschland**s***, if it is a German town. *Südlich von* would indicate that it is south outside of Germany, in Switzerland, Austria or Italy.

Comment: That's probably the most important remark.